# Inconsistency in describing the tribes in Bemidbar 34:19-28

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, masei

In naming the heads of the tribes in [parshat Mas'ei](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0434.htm#19), there is an inconsistency when naming the heads of the tribes of Yehuda and Binyamin. The word *bnai* ("sons of") is not mentioned before the name of these tribes as it is used for all the others.

Also *nasi* ("head") is not mentioned for Yehuda, Binyamin or Shimon.

Why are these words missing for just these tribes?

Comment: both are good questions addressed by mefarshim.  See [here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bemidbar/34.19#e0n7).  I'm too busy to make a formal answer out of it...

Comment: BTW, Dan and @DoubleAA, I think that point about Nasi not being mentioned should be a separate question...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I don't have access now to your link. If you want, briefly explain why these issues are unrelated.

Comment: why would you think that they are related?  One refers to the name of the shevet, one refers to the title of the person.  Also the nasi thing is also for shimon...

Comment: @DanF Have you noticed that the leaders of Reuven and Gad are not mentioned?

Comment: @Eli83 Of course they aren't mentioned! Read the beginning of the section. It refers to the leaders that are responsible for inheriting the land in Cana'an. Reuven and Gad already received their portion of the land on the east side of the Jordan River.

Comment: @DanF but the deal with them was to fight with the 10 other tribes to conquer the land, so I would have thought shevet Reuven and Gad would need a Nasi, no?

Comment: @Eli83 I urge you to read the beginning and end of that section. I believe the 2nd pasuk (verse) specifically says, "These are the people who will inherit the land for you". I.e., it I snot focused on who will fight with them. As a matter of fact, during battle, it's possible that the other tribes had different leaders than those mentioned here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In his commentary on these verses, [R' Samson Raphael Hirsch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Raphael_Hirsch) suggests related tentative answers to both of these questions.

First, he suggests that "מטה בני" - "the tribe of the sons of" - connotes "the tribe as the higher unit to which the individual -בני subordinate themselves." Given that, perhaps Yehuda and Binyamin, for whom the בני is missing, are meant to be thought of as more subordinate themselves to the larger whole of the nation than the other tribes are, since their territory was destined to have the national Temple on it.

Related to that, these two tribes, and Shim'on, which lived inside Yehuda's territory, perhaps thought of their own tribal leaders as a little less elevated ("נשיא") than the other tribes did theirs, since they were so close to the geographic focus of God's sovereignty.